# Copying unsigned char in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, memcpy

I want to use [memcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) but it seems to me that it's copying the array from the start?

I wish to copy from `A[a]` to `A[b]`. So, instead I found an alternative way,

```
void copy_file(char* from, int offset, int bytes, char* to) {
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = offset; i <= (offset+bytes); i++) to[i] = from[j++];
}
```

I'm getting seg faults but I don't know where I am getting this seg fault from?
each entry holds 8 bytes so my second attempt was

```
void copy_file(char* from, int offset, int bytes, char* to) {
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 8*offset; i <= 8*(offset+bytes); i++) to[i] = from[j++];
}
```

but still seg fault. If you need more information please don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: memcpy has no concept of arrays, it copies a number of bytes with the source and destination addresses as arguments.

Comment: If `bytes` is the number of bytes to copy then you are copying too many; the end condition should be `<` instead of `<=`

Comment: Please clarify whether `offset` is an offset into `from`, or an offset into `to`. (Currently you are reading from the start of `from` , and applying the offset to `to`).  It would be even better if you could include some code that calls this function and show the expected inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm getting seg faults but I don't know where I am getting this seg fault from?

*Primary Suggestion: Learn to use a debugger. It provides helpful information about erroneous instruction(s).*

---

To answer you query on the code snippet shown on above question,

1. Check the incoming pointers (`to` and `from`) against `NULL` before dereferencing them.
2. Put a check on the boundary limits for indexes used. Currently they can overrun the allocated memory.

---

To use `memcpy()` properly:

as per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy), the signature of `memcpy()` indicates

> void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);

it copies `n` bytes from address pointer by `src` to address pointed by `dest`.

Also, a very very important point to note:

> ***The memory areas must not overlap.***

So, to copy  A[a] to A[b], you may write something like

```
memcpy(destbuf, &A[a], (b-a) );
```

Comment: oh yes! I think the second one might be the case! thanks for reminding me! let me set this up and try again =]

Answer (score 1):

> it seems to me that `memcpy` copying the array from the start

No, it does not. In fact, `memcpy` does not have a slightest idea that it is copying from or to an array. It treats its arguments as pointers to unstructured memory blocks.

If you wish to copy from `A[a]` to `A[b]`, pass an address of `A[a]` and the number of bytes between `A[b]` and `A[a]` to `memcpy`, like this:

```
memcpy(Dest, &A[a], (b-a) * sizeof(A[0]));
```

This would copy the content of `A` from index `a`, inclusive, to index `b`, exclusive, into a memory block pointed to by `Dest`. If you wish to apply an offset to `Dest` as well, use `&Dest[d]` for the first parameter. Multiplication by `sizeof` is necessary for arrays of types other than `char`, signed or unsigned.

Comment: That should be `b-a` instead of `A[b]-A[a]`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line from

```
for (i = offset; i <= (offset+bytes); i++)
to[i] = from[j++];
```

to

```
for (i = offset; i <= bytes; i++,j++)
to[j] = from[i];
```

This works fine for me. I have considered `offset` as the start of the array and `byte` as the end of the array. ie to copy `from[offset]` to `from[bytes]` to `to[]`.